# VS 2013 Instrumentation Profiling Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

We seem to be running into an issue where we do not get profiling numbers back for one of our assemblies when we run Instrumentation Profiling in VS 2013. A single solution with one executable and multiple project class libraries.

We know that we are running code in this one particular assembly, but when we look at the profiling report from the session, we don't see any information for any functions in it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. If the class library you want to profile is not added as a reference to the executable project, instrumentation for that assembly won't work. The odd thing is that sampling will work even if the class library project is not included as a reference in the executable.

Because our executable project didn't reference the assembly directly, we never noticed the issue because the output of all class projects get copied to the output directories of the executable projects.